# What's the difference between writing routes in meteor.startup and not

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I notice that Telescope write routes in Meteor.startup function.

`Meteor.startup( function () {
  Router.route('/comments/:_id', {
    name: 'comment_reply',
    template: getTemplate('comment_reply'),
    controller: CommentPageController,
    onAfterAction: function() {
      window.queueComments = false;
    }
  });
});`

But I just write route without using the startup function wrapped.
Is there any affects?

Comment: I put my routes outside `Meteor.startup`, in the global scope. Seems like the right place to me; create the routes before the application starts. Don't know if there's any difference between them though.

Comment: Wrapping code in a `startup` callback can be a hack to ensure that it's evaluated after all of the non-startup code. I suspect that's what is going on here.

Answer (score 1):

When using Iron-Router you should make sure, that your routes are available at all times. So you can wrap them into a startup function or put them into /lib. 
When putting them into /lib the routes will be available to both environments.

The best practise (according to Discover Meteor) is a file named router.js in the lib-folder:

```
/lib/router.js:

Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'layout' //the layoutTemplate for all routes will be 'layout'
  //options for every route
});

Router.route('/home', {
  //options for the route with the path '/home'
})
```

[More Information](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md)